# Evaluate $ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan(4x)}{\sin(7x)}$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \  \frac{\tan(4x)}{\sin(7x)}$$

I am stuck after I convert tan(4x) into sin (4x) / cosine(4x)

Comment: $x \to\infty$ or $x\to 0$? If the former, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry. It's tending to zero-

Comment: Try multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{x}$, then multiply the numerator by $\frac{4}{4}$, and the denominator by $\frac{7}{7}$ as follows
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(4x)}{\sin(7x)}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot\frac{\frac{4}{4}}{\frac{7}{7}}=\dots$$
**Hint**

recall that
$$\tan\gamma = \frac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\gamma}$$

Comment: Thanks John Joy. That was the best explanation I ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers are correct and valid. If you know l'Hôpital's rule, there's another way. Observe:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan(4x)}{\sin(7x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\tan(4x)}{\frac{d}{dx}\sin(7x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{4\sec^2(4x)}{7\cos(7x)} = \frac{4}{7}\frac{\sec^2(0)}{\cos(0)} = \frac{4}{7}\frac{1}{1} = \frac{4}{7}$$

Answer (score 4):

Recall that $\lim_{x\to0} \sin(x)/x = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \tan(x)/x = 1$.

Then $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan(4x)}{\sin(7x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{7}{7} \cdot \frac{4x}{4x} \cdot \frac{\tan(4x)}{\sin(7x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{4}{7} \frac{\tan(4x)}{4x} \cdot \frac{7x}{\sin(7x)} = \frac47 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \frac47.$$

---

Once we accept that $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} =1$ it immediately follows that $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\tan(x)}{x} = 1$, since $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\tan(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos(x)} = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$$

Comment: How did you get 4x in the denominator?

Comment: When you are computing these limits, you must match the denominator with the argument inside of $\sin$ or $\tan$ in order to apply the identity $\lim_{x\to 0} \tan(x)/x =0$. Thus if we want to compute $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan(4x)}{x}$$ we must multiply and divide by 4 in order to apply our knowledge of the limits.

Comment: Thus we have $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\tan(4x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} 4 \frac{\tan(4x)}{4x} = 4 \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\tan(4x)}{4x} = 4 \cdot 1.$$

Comment: Similarly we wanted $4x$ under $\tan(4x)$ and $4x$ over $\sin(4x)$, so we multiplied and divided by $4x$. You will notice that we not only have $4x$ under $\tan(4x)$ but we also have $4x$ over $\sin(4x)$.

Comment: Yet, it looks as if you multiplied only the numerator by 4. Also, where is the x coming from. Or is the trig function always depicted a sin(x) = sin(x) / x (are these two equivalent)?

Comment: Those are not equivalent. The idea is that both $\sin(x)$ and $x$ are going to zero, so if you were to try find the limit by simply taking the ratio of their limits you will arrive at $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \frac00$ which is indeterminant. This means that we can't determine the limit by simply computing the ratio of the limits. Without more knowlege, the limit could be $0$, $\infty$, or anything inbetween. Without getting into to much detail, the $x$ counterbalances $\sin(x)$ as both functions tend to zero. Thus the limit becomes $1$. There are various proofs of this out there.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $\lim_{x\to 0} \cos(4x) = 1$, and
\begin{equation*}
  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(4x)}{\sin(7x)} = \frac{4}{7}\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(4x)}{4x}\cdot\frac{7x}{\sin(7x)}\right).
\end{equation*}